# How do I reduce the amount of defined sorting functions that I need?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have written a class to store information about students and have stored instances of this class in a vector. All the information stored in the student class is in string form. I would like to be able to sort the order of the vector by using the [sort function](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) but I don't want to have to have multiple sort bool functions as I currently do.

This is the class code:

```
class studentrecord{
    private:
    string firstname, lastname, grade;        
    public:
    studentrecord(string firstname, string lastname, string grade){
        this -> firstname = firstname;
        this -> lastname = lastname;
        this -> grade = grade;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const studentrecord& studentrecord) {
        os << "\n\t" << studentrecord.firstname << "\t" << studentrecord.lastname << "\t" << studentrecord.grade;
        return os;
    }

    string getfirstname(){
        return firstname;
    }

    string getlastname(){
        return lastname;
    }

    string getgrade(){
        return grade;
    }
};
```

These are the bool sorting functions that I have written:

```
bool comparefirstname(studentrecord* A, studentrecord* B) {
return (A->getfirstname() < B->getfirstname());
}

bool comparelastname(studentrecord* A, studentrecord* B) {
    return (A->getlastname() < B->getlastname());
}

bool comparegrade(studentrecord* A, studentrecord* B) {
    return (A->getgrade() < B->getgrade());
}
```

This is how I have sorted the vector and displayed it:

```
displayRecords(records);
sort(records.begin(), records.end(), comparefirstname);
displayRecords(records);
sort(records.begin(), records.end(), comparelastname);
displayRecords(records);
sort(records.begin(), records.end(), comparegrade);
displayRecords(records);
```

The problem I see is that if I had more member variables that needed to be sorted and displayed I would end up rewriting a lot of code. Is there a way that I wouldn't have to do this?

Comment: Are you able to use C++20?

Comment: Well, sort of, but not really. Any new ordering of that object requires  a new sort incantation.

Comment: If I may suggest, function names like `sortLastName` are misleading, as no sorting is taking place. Perhaps something like `compareLastNames` would be more apt.

Comment: Yeah good point @Chris, Thanks!

Comment: @Captain Giraffe since all the sorting is alphabetic it seems like there would surely be a better way to implement it?

Comment: For instance Could I put the arguments returned by the bool functions directly into the sort functions allowing for the bool functions to not be defined?

Comment: @RossAylen No not really, just write an aptly named functor/function/lambda for each one. Any kind of template magic would just make this easy to read code ... hard to read.